# How to enable/disable buttons in excel at once based on criteria?

Tags: vba

I have an excel file with full command buttons, I want to disable some buttons with one click.
I'll appreciate your help.
Thanks

Comment: Do you have any code with what you have tried so far?

Comment: Are you talking about a form with button, or on a sheet? Just add VBA code like "Me.cmdEditSomething.Enabled = False"

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! I have an excel database with a lot of macros and in a worksheet I created a switchboard, on workbook_open it Popups a user form to asking username and password, thus I want to enable some of buttons for someone user, For example I want to if user name ="Ahmad" and password ="1234" then enable some buttons. else do some thing.hope you got me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With the details you provided in your question, I would say that what you look for is:

1. By default, all the buttons are saved with `ButtonX.Enabled = False` (some of them might default with the `Enabled = True` property if they are meant to be available to all the users);
2. When the user inputs username and password in the form, you might want to run a code like this:

   ```
   If userNameBox.Text = "Ahmad" And passwordBox.Text = "1234" Then
       Button1.Enabled = True
       Button3.Enabled = True
       Button5.Enabled = True
       'and so on with the buttons you want to activate
   End If
   ```

Of course, this should be the code of the event-macro related to the submission of the Username/Password user form, let's say:

```
Private Sub StartUserFormButton_Click()
    'code here
End Sub
```